# Kotlin. Deprecation with multiple choice

Tags: kotlin, deprecated

### What is the best option to provide a multiple-choice deprecation in Kotlin?

I'm trying to find the best way to provide a replacement for deprecated parameter.

Having a enum class `A` with a deprecated element `X`

```
enum class A {
  @Derecated
  X,
  Y,
  Z
}
```

I want IDE to suggest a quickfix replacement for `X` in my code.
To support it I can provide a `replaceWith` value. However, it's not possible to provide a multiple-choice option.

`X` could be replaced with `Y` or `Z`.

```
enum class A {
  @Derecated(
    message = "...",
    replaceWith = ReplaceWith("Y or Z"),
    DeprecationLevel.WARNING,
  )
  X,
  Y,
  Z
}
```

With `ReplaceWith("Y or Z")` IDE can suggest a quickfix, but it will break a compilation:

```
// works, but breaks compilation
A.X -> A.Y or Z
```

Comment: AFAIK `ReplaceWith` should only point to a functional replacement, if you somehow expanded your API with additional options and can't provide a default one then omitting `replaceWith` to force user to read the message and updated docs to explain them seems to be the right choice. I guess you want to have them listed in drop down menu but it sounds like a feature request to me.

Comment: I didn't see "functional replacement" anywhere in docs, but it makes a lot of sense (for tools mainly) to provide a default replacement. I was close to file this in YouTrack, but decided to test my like here :)